# I got a mistake when installing a printer. I chose do not provide the URI number, when I should said yes

Tags: wireless, printing, wired, url

I got a multi functional printer, Brother brand, Model DCP-T510W. I downloaded the drivers as the web page recommended and everything was running well. Nonetheless, when a question comes and asked: --Will you specify the Device URI? [Y/n] ->n --  I said no.

Could you let me know how could I got back my wrong decision? Also,

Can you teach me, where could I get the URI number?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 64bit

Comment: Simply delete the printer, and add it again, correctly.

Comment: Hi, I am taking the first steps along. Could you let me know how can I delete it?. I tried dpkg --list, but, I could not identify the software I want to delete.

Comment: More information. The printer even connectred via USB, does not print at all.

Comment: Browse to `http://localhost:631`, the CUPS interface.

Comment: waltinator: Thank you. I could removed the printer easy with the information in your comment. And before download again the drivers, investigate the IP address, that finally got from my modem and assigned to the printer. It was a hard learning curve. Nonetheless, the printer is set now. Now, I need to figureout how the scanner can be use from the desktop.